# Adding a list of nodes to a TreeView control with only one branch/leaf per node

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm trying to add all the elements of an array to a TreeView control with C#.

The requirement is that every element is a leaf of the previous element in the tree.

So:

first element is root
second is leaf of root
third is leaf of second
etc.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please flag an answer below (even if it is your own) so that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

Example Collection of Nodes:

```
List<TreeNode> oNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

.. Initialization ..

var currentNode = oNodes[0];
oTreeView.Nodes.Add(currentNode);

foreach (var oNode in oNodes.Skip(1)){
   oNode.Parent = currentNode;
   oTreeView.Nodes.Add(oNode);
   currentNode = oNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, but I actually ended up with something like the following:

```
TreeNode[] nodeList=new TreeNode[myString.Length-2];

/* ------------initialization-------------- */

for (int i = 1; i <nodeList.Length; i++)
{            
    nodeList[i].Nodes.Add(nodeList[i - 1]);
}

parentNode.Nodes.Add(nodeList[nodeList.Length-1]);
```